# Adding element to CSV from hasmap Java

Tags: java, csv

I want to read in a CSV and add an element to the row and then write it back out.  So far I have this:

```
private static void appendToCsv(HashMap<String, String> hashMap) throws IOException {
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(""));
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(""), ',');
    String[] entries = null;
    while ((entries = reader.readNext()) != null) {
         ArrayList list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(entries));
         list.add(hashMap.get(list.get(7))); // Add the new element here
         System.out.println(list);
         writer.writeAll(list);
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

I am able to read it in, however I cant write to it. I get an error:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I print the list and it is what I want I also tried writer.writeNext();

Comment: Whole stacktrace please (and show us which line throws that exception) and a link to the used library. (Is it this one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/ ?)

Comment: If you use generic `ArrayList` instead of raw `ArrayList` it will avoid these kind of cryptic problems.

Comment: Heck the API documentation for `CSVwriter.write()`. You are trying to pass it an ArrayList. You should be passing it ArrayList <String []>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is the write takes a

```
List<String[]> allLines
```

you have used raw type

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(entries));
```

you can change that to

```
List<String []> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(entries));
```

and that should work fine for you.